# Same variables within one code, will mysql_query work properly?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wondering if i can use 2 variables with the same name on the same code and it will still work or i need to give every query a diff name? (I know its a super simple question) ;)

Here is an example:

```
$sql="DELETE FROM apps WHERE app_id='".$app_id."'";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$sql="DELETE FROM statistics_apps WHERE app_id='".$app_id."'";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Do i need to change the second `$sql` to `$sql2`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do i need to change the second $sql to $sql2?

No. as long as you make sure to execute $sql (version1) before $sql (version2)
There's no need.

On the other hand **if** you are doing:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM apps WHERE app_id='".$app_id."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$sql="SELECT *  FROM statistics_apps WHERE app_id='".$app_id."'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

You must safe the `$result` query handle in different vars, if you do not fetch all rows from query1 **before** you are start with query2.

Answer (score 1):

as long as you call your first `mysql_query($sql)` before you refill your $sql-variable, it is no problem. You just use one variable which you just give another value :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change your `$sql` variable. What you need is keep the return value of `mysql_query`.

```
$sql="DELETE FROM apps WHERE app_id='".$app_id."'";
$query1 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$sql="DELETE FROM statistics_apps WHERE app_id='".$app_id."'";
$query2 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

var_dump(mysql_affected_rows($query1)); // deleted in apps
var_dump(mysql_affected_rows($query2)); // deleted in statistics_apps
```

Comment: if he doesnt need the return value, he doesnt need to assign it to a variable :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to have a separate variable for each query, unless you need/want to refer to the original query at some later point in the code.

Answer (score 1):

No you do not... because at the end it like write that:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM apps WHERE app_id='".$app_id."'") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("DELETE FROM statistics_apps WHERE app_id='".$app_id."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

the value of your variable `$sql` is changed